# Number of arguments in Haskell code and type is different, why?

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, arguments, type-signature

Can anybody explain the code below, what it does step by step, please. I know it is defining a function and its inputs, but what does `(+)` do, and why are there three `Int`s in `plus` and *four* `Int`s in `plusplus`'s type, while it seems like there are *only 3 arguments* in `plusplus`'s code?

```
 plus :: Int -> Int -> Int 
 plus = (+)

 plusPlus :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
 plusPlus a b c = a + b + c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is the addition operator.  Putting an operator in parentheses, like `(+)`, refers to the addition function itself, as opposed to using `+` to add two numbers right on the spot.  Basically, this:

```
plus = (+)
```

is equivalent to:

```
plus a b = a + b
```

Either way, it is defining `plus` to be a synonym for `+`.

In Haskell, `->` is used to separate the types of the arguments, *as well as the return value*.  So,

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

is a function which takes two `Int`s and returns an `Int`.

```
plusPlus :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

is a function which takes three `Int`s and returns an `Int`.

The reason why the syntax is the same for the arguments and the return value is due to [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

To be really pedantic,

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int                -- ~  Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

is a function which takes an `Int`, and returns a function which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`.

```
plusPlus :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int     -- ~  Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))
```

is a function which takes an `Int`, and returns a function which takes an `Int`, and returns a function which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`.

In practice, it's convenient to speak of Haskell functions as taking multiple arguments.  But technically, Haskell functions always take one argument.  The argument type is on the left side of `->`, and the return type is on the right side of `->`, but the return type might itself be another function.